# How do I keep two separate, centered words on the same line during screen-size change?

Tags: html, css

Please note, I am not allowed to change the HTML here, only the CSS can be changed. I want the two words to stay on the same line when the screen becomes smaller (as long as whitespace remains on either side, at least), however they currently collapse quite readily, even though a lot of whitespace remains to either side.

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVzRbg

```css
html {
}
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#link {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  left: 45%;
  right: 45%;
}
#link a {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #fefefe;
  background-color: rgb(75, 101, 198, 1);
  /*line-height: 20px;*/
  padding: 10px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #3c58c7;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#link a:hover {
  background-color: #354eb1
}
#one {
  border: 5px solid rgb(242, 168, 60, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
}
#two {
  border: 5px solid rgb(55, 124, 33, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
}
#three {
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 253, 85, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
}
#four {
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 34, 245, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling
       rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="blocks.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="one">
    Turns out you have a really fun time if you
    go to work every day and focus on being
    silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence,
    and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters
    fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never
    mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
    small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
  </div>
  <p id="link">
    <a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
      Brainy Quote
    </a>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by only a small css change. Change your styling of id `link` to:

```
#link {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```css
html {}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#link {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#link a {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #fefefe;
  background-color: rgb(75, 101, 198, 1);
  /*line-height: 20px;*/
  padding: 10px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #3c58c7;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#link a:hover {
  background-color: #354eb1
}

#one {
  border: 5px solid rgb(242, 168, 60, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
}

#two {
  border: 5px solid rgb(55, 124, 33, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
}

#three {
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 253, 85, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
}

#four {
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 34, 245, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling
       rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="blocks.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one">
    Turns out you have a really fun time if you go to work every day and focus on being silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
  </div>
  <p id="link">
    <a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
      Brainy Quote
    </a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 spans with display: inline-block; or float: left;

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am not allowed to change the HTML. I did try to make the `#link a{}` part have a `display: inline-block;` however it did not change the behavior.

Comment: in CSS, try:
white-space: nowrap;

Comment: That certainly helped, thanks! Quick question, I'm curious why the right side has less whitespace than the left, when the page gets smaller, however? I want it to stay in the middle. I made a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVzRbg for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning left and right to an absolute item without declaring width on the P causes the lines to break.

It is better to center it like this:

```
width: 150px; (or any other measurement you chose)    
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 5px auto;
```

I suggest reading these posts about centering:

- [smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)
- [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: Thanks for the link suggestions. I did my best to incorporate your answers into a codepen as I understood (since the formatting was not 100% clear to me, such as "substitute for this: `#link{...`," but ran into a problem of the left side having less whitespace than the right side, when making the window smaller. The codepen showing what I mean when using your answer is at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxKyga. Another poster added an answer that worked and I have accepted that as the correct one.